# Select a row or rows only when a status change in status column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sample data as below in Oracle Table (CarStatus) on a date range of 01mar14 to 31mar14:

```
CarID | CarModel | Date    | StatusCode | Duration
100   | Toyota   | 01Mar14 | Ready      | 24
100   | Toyota   | 02Mar14 | Ready      | 24
100   | Toyota   | 03Mar14 | Ready      | 12
100   | Toyota   | 03Mar14 | Workshop   | 03
100   | Toyota   | 03Mar14 | Inspection | 09
100   | Toyota   | 04Mar14 | Inspection | 04
100   | Toyota   | 04Mar14 | Ready      | 20
100   | Toyota   | 05Mar14 | Ready      | 24
............
100   | Toyota   | 31Mar14 | Ready      | 24
200   | Honda    | 01Mar14 | Workshop   | 24
200   | Honda    | 02Mar14 | Workshop   | 24
200   | Honda    | 03Mar14 | Workshop   | 10
200   | Honda    | 03Mar14 | Inspection | 14
200   | Honda    | 04Mar14 | Inspection | 04
200   | Honda    | 04Mar14 | Ready      | 20
200   | Honda    | 05Mar14 | Ready      | 24
200   | Honda    | 06Mar14 | Ready      | 24
200   | Honda    | 07Mar14 | Ready      | 24
...................
200   | Honda    | 31Mar14 | Ready      | 24
```

I want the result to only pick up the rows where the values have changed. The output should be:

```
CarID | CarModel | Date    | StatusCode | Duration
100   | Toyota   | 01Mar14 | Ready      | 24   
100   | Toyota   | 03Mar14 | Ready      | 12
100   | Toyota   | 03Mar14 | Workshop   | 03
100   | Toyota   | 03Mar14 | Inspection | 09
100   | Toyota   | 04Mar14 | Inspection | 04
100   | Toyota   | 04Mar14 | Ready      | 20
100   | Toyota   | 05Mar14 | Ready      | 24
200   | Honda    | 01Mar14 | Workshop   | 24   
200   | Honda    | 03Mar14 | Workshop   | 10
200   | Honda    | 03Mar14 | Inspection | 14
200   | Honda    | 04Mar14 | Inspection | 04
200   | Honda    | 04Mar14 | Ready      | 20
200   | Honda    | 05Mar14 | Ready      | 24
```

Can anyone help me with the query please? Or the Logic to only pick up the above conditional records? The above duration column is Hrs / day....This table maintains the status of the carID on every day, each hourly basis

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is datatype of `Date` column?

Comment: Use `distinct` for Duration column to get the required result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the LAG function with which you can see data in the previous record. Unfortunately it cannot be used in a where clause, so you need an inner and an outer select.

```
select carid, carmodel, statusdate, statuscode, duration
from
(
  select carstatus.*, lag(duration) over (order by carid, statusdate) AS previous_duration
  from carstatus
)
where duration <> nvl(previous_duration,-1)
order by carid, statusdate;
```

I renamed your date statusdate, as date is a reserved word.

(BTW: Is carmodel really a column of the carstatus table? It's the same for every carid, so it should be in a car table rather than in a status table.)

Comment: Thanks Thorsten for your reply. I will try lag() to see if I can tweek my query. I am sorry about giving this example, I actually work in Aviation industry and do not have authority to disclose in detail, so gave this car example. The above model is just to get logic or functions used.... Thanks.. i will get back to u after trying your example

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, your logic and function worked. It was so simple. I really appreciate your time answering my question...

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT in your query to leave unique results only. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: What about date column?